# Getting first values from composite type arrays

Tags: arrays, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

```
CREATE TABLE people(   
name_ varchar(50) NOT NULL,
count int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE TABLE person_added(
date_ date NOT NULL,
all_people_ people[],
all_people_count int NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE all_people_array_table(
id SERIAL,
people_array person_added[]
);


{"(2016-02-27,{(Jack,3),(John,6)},1000)","(2016-03-27,{(Ben,3),(Francis,6)},2000)"}
```

`people_array` contains of `person_added` composite types. And I need to get dates in this array. (2016-02-27 and 2016-03-27)

I guess I need to use slice but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`unnest()` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS) to convert the array into a set of rows:

```
SELECT date_
FROM all_people_array_table, unnest(people_array);
```

The `unnest()` function is a table function so you use it like you would a table name. Such table functions can use columns from previously specified relations (see section on "LATERAL Subqueries" following the section in the link above).

But you should really review your table design. Working with arrays like this undermines the relational structure of the data. Your design looks more like a [hierarchical model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_database_model), the database design paradigm from the 1960's. Instead of arrays, use keys from one table to the next.